# Pushing files to github

Tags: git, github

I have used git push command and it has worked as expected so far. While testing the git commands today I found that pushing to HEAD instead of master works without an error as shown below.
I will like to learn the difference between these two commands so that I can choose the correct one.

```
# git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
To git@github.com:shan/mobileapp
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:shan/mobileapp'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.


# git push origin HEAD
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 23, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.56 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:shan/mobileapp
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> topic/wip
```

Pushing it to head seems to have created branch called topic/wip

I can now merge the branch topic/wip with master. But I will like the first command mentioned above to work as expected. And I do not need to create a temporary branch to be merged with master.

Comment: You should be merging in origin/master before trying to push to it, as explained in the error message you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git `HEAD` basically means "the current commit". So when you've checked out the `wip` branch, `git push origin HEAD` is equivalent to `git push origin wip`, which will push to the remote branch `origin/wip`, creating it if it needs to, as shown in your second example.

The reason you were unable to push to master was that your local copy of the branch was outdated. You'll need to update your local copy before you push: `git pull origin master`.